# Extracting a long attribute value with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

reedit again

ok, I need to parse some site and can you help me parse this weird ?

```
    <div class="cloudzoom-gallery e-item-card-photos-small_item" data-cloudzoom="
 useZoom:"#item_card_zoom", image:"/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg", zoomImage:"/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg""> <img width="44" src="/upload/66/32x44/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880_32x44.jpg" title="Product1" alt="LGTV"></div>
```

all I need from this div, information about image, link of image, how can I do it?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I've changed code and "expanded" the question

Comment: Python code indentation is still bad. And please include import statements and variable definitions (see [mcve]).

Comment: please, check again

Comment: what's the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
x = '''
<div class="cloudzoom-gallery e-item-card-photos-small_item" data-cloudzoom="
 useZoom:"#item_card_zoom", image:"/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg", zoomImage:"/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg""> <img width="44" src="/upload/66/32x44/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880_32x44.jpg" title="Product1" alt="LGTV"></div> '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html5lib')
div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'cloudzoom-gallery e-item-card-photos-small_item'})
print(div.img['src'])
print(div.img['title'])
print(div.img['alt'])
```

This prints the image url, title and alt:

```
/upload/66/32x44/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880_32x44.jpg 
Product1
LGTV
```

Post your comment, since you want the larger image, there is a pattern discernible that can be exploited to get the work done:

1) File name is same: `66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880` except with a underscore and size appended to the smaller image.

2) Folder name is the first two letters of the filename, `66` in this case.

3) File path of larger image is same except for the size appended in the middle like `32x44`

Based on these, we can easily create the path for the larger image like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
x = '''
<div class="cloudzoom-gallery e-item-card-photos-small_item" data-cloudzoom="
 useZoom:"#item_card_zoom", image:"/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg", zoomImage:"/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg""> <img width="44" src="/upload/66/32x44/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880_32x44.jpg" title="Product1" alt="LGTV"></div> '''
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html5lib')
div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'cloudzoom-gallery e-item-card-photos-small_item'})
file_name = div.img['src'].split("_")[0].split("/")[-1]
extension = div.img['src'].split(".")[-1]
folder_name = file_name[0:2]
final_file_path = "/upload/" + folder_name + "/" + file_name + "." + extension
print(final_file_path)
```

This prints:

```
/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg
```

Another simpler option is to simply take the div string and split it appropriately like so:

```
print(x.split("image:")[1].split(",")[0])
```

This would print the image url:

```
"/upload/66/66ef9b3de11aeaba1bc50a42a1c8b880.jpg"
```

Beautiful soup provides a way to get data attributes like so:

```
div.attrs['data-cloudzoom']
```

However since the data attribute here has further un-escaped double quotes within double quotes, beautiful soup cannot work here. You can also note that the html you have posted above in the question fails to get proper color highlight from stackoverflow because of that very reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but as you see img tag store different type of url than in div, it's a small photo url

Comment: modified my answer